# comparing of two lists of matrices in python

Tags: python

I want to compare two lists with matrices as the elements, see which elements are not in the second list, and print them.

I have two lists and I used the if condition. This is the error I'm getting: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

This is the code:

```
new_list1 = [] 
for i in A: 
    if i not in B: 
        new_list1.append(i) 
        print("elements of list 1 that are not present in list 2 ",new_list1)
```

where `A` and `B` are the two lists.

Comment: your code please

Comment: what is your code to compare?

Comment: This is the code:
new_list1 = []
for i in A:
    if i not in B:
        new_list1.append(i)
print("elements of list 1 that are not present in list 2 ",new_list1)

Comment: A and B are the two lists.

Comment: Add information about the type of elements in the lists, namely whether they are [numpy ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) or some other objects. In other words, provide [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your lists store `np.array`s as elements. That is why your code doesn't work (though should work with simple nested lists).

```
A = [
        [
            [1,1,1,],
            [2,2,2,],
            [3,3,3,],
        ],
        [
            [1,2,3,],
            [4,5,6,],
            [7,8,9,],
        ]
    ]

B = [
        [
            [1,2,3,],
            [4,5,6,],
            [7,8,9,],
        ]
    ]

A = [np.array(mat) for mat in A]
B = [np.array(mat) for mat in B]

new_list1 = []
for i in A:
    if i not in B:
        new_list1.append(i)
        print("elements of list 1 that are not present in list 2 ", new_list1)
```

```
python3 main.py
>>> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If this is the case (I can't comment and ask for details), you can use this code for your task.

```
# Iterate through the matrices in A
for matrix1 in A:
    # Iterate through the matrices in B
    for matrix2 in B:
        # Use np.array_equal to compare matrices element-wise
        if np.array_equal(matrix1, matrix2):
            break
    # If no match was found in B, add the matrix to not_in_B
    else:
        not_in_B.append(matrix1)

# Print the matrices that are not in B
for matrix in not_in_B:
    print(matrix)
```

shorter

```
not_in_B = [matrix for matrix in A if not any(np.array_equal(matrix, b) for b in B)]
```

Or numpy-like

```
A_array = np.array(A)
B_array = np.array(B)

equal_arrays = np.all(A_array[:, None] == B_array, axis=(2, 3))

# Find the arrays that are not in B
not_in_B = A_array[~np.any(equal_arrays, axis=1)]
```

**UPD**.
In case you are working with large data you should consider more optimal way than written above.

One of them is to convert np.arrays to tuples and do set difference. For example,

```
set1 = {tuple(map(tuple, arr)) for arr in A}
set2 = {tuple(map(tuple, arr)) for arr in B}

# Find the arrays that are in list1 but not in list2
not_in_B = [np.array(arr) for arr in set1 - set2]

# Print the arrays that are not in list2
for arr in not_in_B:
    print(arr)
```

Comment: i think that my code may be written much better. For example, it may be rewritten with `for ... if ... break ... else ...`
but for now main goal is to understand that np.arrays should be handled different than lists.

Comment: edited main solution and add numpy-like

Answer (score 0):

Yes, handling numpy as a littlie different that normal lists.

```
import numpy as np

# Example lists of matrices A and B
A = [np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])]
B = [np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), np.array([[9, 10], [11, 12]])]

new_list = []

for matrix_a in A:
    presense='0'
    for matrix_b in B:
        if np.array_equal(matrix_a, matrix_b):
            presense='Yes'
            break
    if presense!='Yes':
        new_list.append(matrix_a)

print(new_list)
```

See relevant literature https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html about numpy.array_equal(a1, a2, equal_nan=False). To be fair my way is similar to one already mentioned, with the addition of the var presence.

Dimitris